# SQL Server - not displaying NULL values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
cas=(
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(15, 2), sum(somme))
AND CAST(DATEP AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE(YEAR, -1, CAST(@DATED AS DATE)) 
                            AND DATEAD(YEAR, -1, CAST(@DAT AS DATE))
GROUP BY etab,
         libelle
```

I want a solution that the query doesn't return the null values.

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: That is displayed by the SQL client you are using not by "SQL Server" - which tool do you use to run your SQL statements?

Comment: add to the `where` clause: `and x is not null and y is not null and z is not null...` (x,y and z should be the columns names

Comment: I strongly suggest learning how to format your code. Using whitespace and good use of linebreaks make your code infinitely more readablef or both yourself and others. Honestly, writing everything left aligned and a lack of line breaks just makes an unreadable mess.

Comment: Here is a formatted version of your query: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f3e055eb8dcb2e72835aeb24a00a465d). It's quite odd as well that you're mixing formats. You start with `{expression} AS '{Literal String Alias}'` and then switch to `{Alias} = {Expression}`. It seems like this query has been written by more than 1 person.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the CA_AN subquery to a Cross Apply and check the is not null on the where clause

```
SELECT 
    REGION = et_region, 
    [STORE CODE] = e.et_etablissement,
    [STORE NAME] = et_libelle,
    CA = CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),SUM(gl_totalttcdev)),
    NBRTICKETS = CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,0),COUNT(distinct(GL_NUMERO))),
    NBRARTICLES =  CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,0),SUM(GL_QTEFACT)),
    UPT =  CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),SUM(GL_QTEFACT)/COUNT(DISTINCT(GL_NUMERO))) ,
    PM =  CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),SUM(gl_totalttcdev)/COUNT(DISTINCT(GL_NUMERO))),
    CA_AN = MAX(CA_AN.caan)

FROM piece 
LEFT JOIN ligne ON 
    gl_souche = gp_souche 
    AND gl_naturepieceg = gp_naturepieceg 
    AND gl_numero = gp_numero 
    AND gl_indiceg = gp_indiceg 
LEFT JOIN etabliss AS e ON
    gp_etablissement = e.et_etablissement 
LEFT JOIN ARTICLE ON 
    GL_CODEARTICLE = ARTICLE.GA_CODEARTICLE
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
        caan = CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),sum(gl_totalttcdev)) 
    FROM piece 
    LEFT JOIN ligne ON 
        gl_souche = gp_souche 
        AND gl_naturepieceg = gp_naturepieceg 
        AND gl_numero = gp_numero 
        AND gl_indiceg = gp_indiceg 
    LEFT JOIN etabliss AS e1 ON 
        e1.et_etablissement = gp_etablissement
    left join ARTICLE on 
        GL_CODEARTICLE = ARTICLE.GA_CODEARTICLE
    where 
        gp_naturepieceg = 'FFO'
        AND gl_typearticle <> ''
        AND gl_typearticle <> 'FI' 
        AND e1.et_etablissement = e.et_etablissement
        AND CAST(GP_DATEPIECE AS DATE) BETWEEN  DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CAST(@DATED AS DATE)) AND DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CAST(@DATEF AS DATE))
    GROUP BY 
        et_etablissement, 
        et_libelle

) CA_AN
WHERE 
    gp_naturepieceg = 'FFO' 
    AND (e.et_etablissement NOT IN ('F20','F44','R05','F40','F47'))
    AND gl_typearticle <> ''
    AND gl_typearticle <> 'FI' 
    AND et_LIBELLE LIKE @MAG
    AND CAST(GP_DATEPIECE AS DATE) BETWEEN  CAST(@DATED AS DATE) AND CAST(@DATEF AS DATE) 
    AND CA_AN.caan IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    et_region,
    et_etablissement, 
    et_libelle
HAVING SUM(gl_totalttcdev) > 0 
ORDER BY 
    et_region,
    CA_AN DESC,
    et_etablissement
```